# Multivariate Normal Distributions and the Uniform Distribution on the Sphere

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

Given a multivariate normal vector $X \sim N(0,I_d)$ (identity covariance matrix), it is well known that :$$\frac{X}{\|X\|_2}
$$
is uniformly distributed on the sphere of radius $\sqrt{d}$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, where here $\|\cdot\|_2$ denotes the usual Euclidean norm.

**Question**: Is this is not the case for **any** rotationally invariant $X$? Roughly speaking, $X$ being rotationally invariant in my mind corresponds to the distribution of $X$ depending only $\|X\|_2$ (radius) and so any normalized rotationally invariant distribution should also be uniformly distributed on the sphere (of course possibly with a different choice of radius).

Is there something special about normality being invoked above? I know that the multivariate normal is the only rotationally invariant distribution with independent components $X_i$ (this is the so-called Maxwell's theorem) but I'm not sure if/where this fact is invoked when showing that normalized versions of $X$ are uniformly distributed on the sphere.

Comment: So just to follow up, I believe the example I am looking at uses normal variables as a convenient baseline/standard. But I will leave this question up in case there is something I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

May I mention this:

Gerard Letac (1981) 'Isotropy and sphericity, some characterisations of the normal distribution.'  Ann. Statist. 9, 408-417.

**The following part was written by @Amir:**

In the [above paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2240799?read-now=1&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), Prof. Letac presented the following characterization of normal distributions:

[image]

Comment: Thank you professor Letac

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed the argument is general for all isotropic distribution. It is for simulations that normal distributions are most interesting. The usual problem is to actually sample uniformly the hypersphere. The naive method of parametrizing the sphere (like generalized spherical coordinates) and finding the corresponding distribution on the parameters is typically too cumbersome.

Instead, it is easier to normalize an isotropic multivariate normal variable. The latter is sampled by sampling each components being independently normally distributed.

Btw, the usual way to sample a normal variable is to do the reverse in $2D$. Indeed the direct method of reverting to a uniform distribution by the cdf is costly as it requires computing the error function. Instead, you can first sample the direction which is uniform, and then radially. Mathematically, you can get a standard normal from:
$$
X=\sqrt{-\ln U}\cos(2\pi\Phi)
$$
with $U,\Phi$ independently and uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. Actually, you get two independent normal distributions by also considering:
$$
Y=\sqrt{-\ln U}\sin(2\pi\Phi)
$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a proof you might point to or provide?

Comment: @LPZ - thank you for your answer. Could I ask what your definition of isotropic is? Mine is zero mean and diagonal covariance, and under that definition there are random vectors that are isotropic but not rotation invariant (for example the uniform distribution on the cube $\{-1,1\}^d$)

Comment: When I say isotropic I mean rotation invariant. It’s for the full rotation group, so I don’t consider the uniform distribution of the hypercube to be isotropic. In particular, if you normalize it, you won’t sample uniformly the hypersphere.

Comment: @Aruralreader, which part do you want to prove? The two claims that the normalizing an isotropic distribution samples uniformly the hypersphere and that the components of an isotropic normal variable are already known to the OP.

Comment: @LPZ, OP is stating his or her intuition about the situation. The question, as I read it,  is about extending beyond a normal distribution: ‘Is this is not the case for any rotationally invariant $X$?’

Comment: Beware about 'Isotropy of $X$'.In the above paper it means that $X/\|X\|$ is uniform on the spere and NOT that the distribution of $X$ is invariant by rotation.